# Building GHC: configure fails on happy despite successful cabal install

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal, happy

I am attempting to build GHC from source following [this page](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Building/QuickStart). When installing dependencies, I had to install `happy` and `alex`:

```
$ cabal install alex happy
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring alex-3.2.1...
Configuring happy-1.19.5...
Building happy-1.19.5...
Building alex-3.2.1...
Installed alex-3.2.1
Installed happy-1.19.5
```

yet when running `configure` I get an error message:

```
$ ./configure
...
checking for happy... no
checking for version of happy... 
configure: error: Happy version 1.19.4 or later is required to compile GHC.
```

I am running on Debian `stretch`:

```
$ uname -a 
Linux <host> 4.8.0-1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.8.5-1 (2016-10-28) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Can anyone suggest an obvious step I could try to resolve this?

Comment: You have to install `happy` and `alex` as Ubuntu package as well: `sudo apt-get install alex happy`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem perfect, this does it thank you !!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suspect you simply don't have them on your PATH. Make sure to include something like

```
PATH="$HOME/.cabal/bin:$PATH"
```

in your .bashrc (or startup files for whatever shell you use). Installing them through the package manager simply installed them in a location that was already on your PATH.

Even if you have things working now, you should consider modifying your .bashrc while it's fresh in your head, as other cabal-install'd executables will get put there in the future.

Comment: Thank you very much Daniel, I have now setup my `.bashrc` file accordingly

Answer (score 5):

You should install `alex` and `happy` as Debian packages as well. On a Debian machine, you can use `apt-get` for that:

```
sudo apt-get install alex happy
```